# What will be the length of slower train?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

when two trains were running in the same direction at 90 km/hr and 70 km/hr then the fastest train passed a man sitting in the slow train in 36 seconds. What is the length of the fastest train?

Ans I found as per answer provided in the book as 200 meters.

i.e (90-70)*36*(5/18) = 200 meters

then what will be the speed of slower train? `As  question never tells us that both are of same length`.. So how to calculate?

Comment: 70 km/h????????

Comment: @StiffJokes: 70 km/hr means?

Comment: "what will be the speed of slower train"

Comment: According to Newton's first law, the speed will be constant if no external force.

Comment: @peterwhy: 70 km/hr

Comment: Are we supposed to use galilean relativity or special relativity :P

Comment: Make sure the question was correctly typed first!

Comment: I like the linear algebra tag lol

Comment: So if special relativity is necessary, then the question is no longer (linear-algebra)? :P

Comment: Title and body are out of sync!

Comment: Stiff Jokes, I think it's pretty obvious what the question is, if you want to submit an edit then you may submit an edit.

Comment: @Matt. Yes, it's not a great problem statement, but it still makes perfect sense, as it says the train "passed" a man, meaning the front of the train was level with him, and then after 36 seconds the back of the train was level with him. It's actually abundantly clear. No one has to be at the head of any train. Look at my answer, the man is only one point. Neither do the trains need to be head to head.

Comment: Length in the title but speed in the body, so what is the correct question?

Comment: Okay, yeah, not sure what he means by what is the speed of the slower train...

Answer (score 1):

From the reference of the Earth, the speeds of trains are $90$ km/h and $70$ km/h respectively. Then the distance of faster train travelled is

$$\text{Distance} = \text{speed}\times\text{time}\\
(90/3.6)\times36 = 900\text{ m}$$

and the distance that the slower train travelled is
$$(70/3.6)\times36 = 700\text{ m}$$

The difference, $200$ m, would be the length of the faster train.

The speed of the slower train is $70$ km/h as given.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter what length the slow train is, because you are only looking at a specific point on it. In fact, you can look at this problem as "Given a fast train moving 90 km/hr, say it takes 36 seconds to pass a man moving 70 km/hr in the same direction."

Which is an easy `Distance = Rate X Time`, where distance is your length (because once the front of the train is level with the man, then it most go one train length to pass the man), rate is just the difference between the two speeds, and time is of course time.